# HTML DIV's inside TD's as href's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello all I want to make the div's I have inside my td's act as href's.  How can I achieve this??

Maybe with jquery or javascript if not with html??

```
<table class="mgmtview_table" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td class="content" id="content">
       <table class="content_table">
       <tr>
         <td class="topBar">
       <div id="div_view" align="center">FusionCharts will load here!</div> 

    </td> 
        <td class="topBar">
        <div id="div_view2" align="center">FusionCharts will load here!</div> 
    </td> 
        <td class="topBar">
        <div id="div_view3" align="center">FusionCharts will load here!</div> 
    </td> 
    </tr>

        <tr>
         <td class="topBar">
         <div id="div_view4" align="center">FusionCharts will load here!</div> 
    </td> 
    <td class="topBar">
         <div id="div_view5" align="center">FusionCharts will load here!</div> 
    </td> 
    <td class="topBar">
         <div id="div_view6" align="center">FusionCharts will load here!</div> 
    </td> 
    </tr>

        <tr>
         <td class="topBar">
         <div id="div_view7" align="center">FusionCharts will load here!</div> 
    </td> 
    <td class="topBar">
         <div id="div_view8" align="center">FusionCharts will load here!</div> 
    </td> 
    <td class="topBar">
         <div id="div_view9" align="center">FusionCharts will load here!</div> 
    </td> 
    </tr>
```

Comment: Why not just use a tags?

Comment: I agree with Immanish - why would you want to do this?

Comment: Indeed. You can style them as `display: block` to make them behave like a block element (like a div), so you can give it width, height and other properties as you would do now with the div. No need for Javascript at all.

Comment: You'll enjoy programming more if you use the proper tags for their intended purpose.

Comment: To the downvoters...Don't just blindly downvote. The OP is obviously a beginner and has made an effort to ask a question even adding a code sample. This place can really feel unwelcoming sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jquery you can do something like this:

```
$('table.content_table td div').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
    location.href='http://google.com';
});
```

But if you want links, then you should really use `<a href="...">`. That's what they're made for. :p

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you don't.

An important rule to remember with html is to use the correct element for the job you wish to do. That's why such a range of elements exists.

One you start messing around switching elements you are opening a can of worms not only with cross browser compatibility but with accessibility.

Use the HTML Anchor element. You can style it pretty much any way you like and you can override default behaviour easily with JavaScript if need be. For more information on the Anchor element check out the information contained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a).